# Using SOAP::Lite client to handle server that sends responses missing namespace specification

Tags: xml, perl, soap, soap-client, soaplite

I'm writing a SOAP::Lite client to work with a SOAP server that sometimes sends responses that are missing a namespace specification. This is the first time I've ever done anything with SOAP, so I'm not very knowledgeable at all. Here is an example response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: "OS/version" UPnP/1.0 "product/version"
Content-Length: 83219
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="UTF-8"
Client-Date: Tue, 01 Aug 2017 06:30:44 GMT
Client-Peer: 192.168.1.123:5000
Client-Response-Num: 1

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-6"?>
<soap-env:Envelope
        xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        soap-env:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        >
<soap-env:Body>
    <m:GetDataResponse
        xmlns:m="urn:BLACKBOX:service:DataSource:1">
        <DataBlob xsi:type="xsd:base64Binary">Ikf7SPJ...SsA==</DataBlob>
    </m:GetDataResponse>
    <ResponseCode>0</ResponseCode>
</soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

Notice the use of the 'xsi' namespace without specification. There should probably be one for 'xsd' too? SOAP::Lite is giving me this error message:

```
failed:  Unresolved prefix 'xsi' for attribute 'xsi:type'
```

How would I work around this with SOAP::Lite in the client, given that I have no control of the server? Is there some way for me to tell SOAP::Lite to assume namespaces I provide?

Answer (score 0):

The server is broken and you should raise an error. Meanwhile, you could get your code working by editing the incoming data, adding

these definitions to the `Envelope` element

```
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

Comment: Yes, I did realize the server is broken and that I want those two definitions added to the Envelope element, but what I need is a description of how to actually use SOAP::Lite to accomplish that editing.

Comment: There's a kind of live stream of the Perl Conference in Amsterdam at https://twitter.com/steve_mynott/status/895222263695409153 if you're interested.

Comment: @simbabque: Thank you.

Comment: Welcome back! :) I missed you.

Comment: @simbabque: Thank you. I doubt if many people share your sentiment! I wish wouldn't do that.I sent you a tweet; did you get it?

Comment: I did not unfortunately. But I found it now and wrote a private message there.

Comment: I just submitted a talk for the London Perl Workshop in November this year. Maybe we can have that pint finally. And if you don't plan to attend I am happy to extend my stay and come to Reading to collect it. There's nothing like a train ride through the London suburbs in dreadful late-autumn weather I guess.

Comment: @simbabque: Sadly I'm in Edinburgh for the foreseeable future caring for my elderly mother while I work. Reading is where I took my degree, but that was in 1978—I'm normally in Norwich these days. What will your subject be?

Comment: Oh, that's a shame. Some other time then. My talk will be about training junior developers. I've already done a lightning talk about that in Amsterdam. This one is going to be longer though.

Comment: @simbabque: I'll catch it on Youtube if it's posted there.

Answer (score 0):

Just add to SOAP::Lite object:

```
$soap->serializer->register_ns('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' => 'xmlns:xsd');

$soap->serializer->register_ns('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' => 'xmlns:xsi');
```

Comment: That cannot work. I need a solution for namespace definitions missing from the incoming SOAP response, not the outgoing request. Is there a way to register such definitions with the **de**serializer so that it will use them when they are missing in the actual incoming response XML?